# error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: django, git, apache, nginx

I am getting an error when trying to push my django code to git which is around 100 MB.

`error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

I tried `http.postbuffer` and also changed nginx and apache2 settings, added `client_max_body_size 500m;`. But i am neither using any of those servers. i am just trying to upload to git. can any one give me the solution?

Answer (score 1):

**When does one get this error?**

This error generally occurs when you try to push a large repository over HTTP.

`http.postBuffer` setting on your git client controls the maximum size in bytes of the buffer to be used when `POSTing` some data. Its default size is `1 MiB` and if you are try to push file greater than this, you get this error.

**Some Possible solutions:**

**1. Setting a higher value for `http.postbuffer` setting**

You can set a higher value for `http.postBuffer` setting on your git client.

```
# increase the Git buffer size to the largest individual file size of your repo
git config --global http.postBuffer <size_in_MiB>
```

**2. Nginx servers:**

**(a) `client_max_body_size` setting**

It can also occur due to default **reverse proxy** configuration settings. One such setting is the `client_max_body_size` setting which sets the maximum allowed size of a request body.

In case of nginx server, default size of `1 Mib` is applied so pushing a repository greater than this results in this error.

From the [`client_max_body_size` setting](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) in nginx docs:

> Sets the maximum allowed size of the client request body, specified in
>   the `“Content-Length”` request header field. **If the size in a request
>   exceeds the configured value, the `413` (Request Entity Too Large) error
>   is returned to the client.** Please be aware that browsers cannot
>   correctly display this error. Setting size to `0` disables checking of
>   client request body size.

To change the `client_max_body_size` setting, load your `nginx.conf` and add `client_max_body_size` setting with value as per your needs  in the `http` block. You can also set `client_max_body_size` setting to `0` which will allows users to push repositories of any size.

```
# nginx.conf    
client_max_body_size <required_size_in_MiB>; # add this setting in the http block to set a custom size
client_max_body_size 0; # to push repositories of any size
```

After adding this setting, you need to reload nginx using `sudo service nginx reload` and then try again to push your commit over http.

**(b) Connection timeout setting**

The reverse proxy may also have a connection timeout that's closing the connection (e.g. `TimeOut` or `ProxyTimeout` in apache, `proxy_read_timeout` in ngnix). Try bypassing the proxy by pushing directly to `IP:port`. If this works, it's highly likely that the proxy server is causing the early disconnect and needs to be tuned.

**3. Apache server:**

You can set the `LimitRequestBody` setting to increase the allowed limit of an HTTP request body.

You need to add `LimitRequestBody` setting to a custom value as per your requirements in the `httpd.conf` file. Setting this value to `0` will allow you to push file of any size.

```
# httpd.conf
LimitRequestBody <custom_size_in_bytes> # set a custom limit
LimitRequestBody 0 # no limit on the size
```

**4. Using SSH instead:**

You can use `SSH` instead of HTTP to push the repository.